# Telerik MVC Extensions deployment problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, web-config, telerik-mvc

I am writing a website which uses Telerik MVC Extensions, and am getting an error on my test server when I get no such error on my development PC.

The error is ...

> Web.config(101): error CS0246: The type
>   or namespace name 'Telerik' could not
>   be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

Here is the relevant line from the web.config file ...

> <add namespace="Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI"/>

I have checked the bin folder on my test server and it does contain the Telerik.Web.Mvc.dll file. The test server is 2008R2.

Have I missed something really obvious here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have multiple applications in your website? In other words, do you have multiple web.config and bin folders?

Comment: yes i did, we've now got just the one application within the website and it works great. thanks.